# テーブルビューの並び替えノブの色を変更する方法

Tags: swift

テーブルビューの並び替えノブの色を変更する方法が分からず詰まっております。
よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そのようなことをサポートする公開APIは存在しないようです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。他の対応方法を検討してみます。